# Finding second largest entry in a column

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a computationally efficient way to find the top-2 entries in a column rather than just the top one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the column, you could do two simple things:

Run max once, remove the max element, run max again and then you have the second highest value.

Alternatively, you could sort the data or use a max heap to store it.  Sorted data is easier to work with.

For small datasets, the first method is going to be more efficient.  For larger sets, it makes more sense to sort it before finding the desired value.

Comment: For a large set, sorting would be even heavier. Sorting is O(nlogn) after all. On a distributed system, it would be even worse.

Comment: Yes, but for a large data set, if you have to traverse it more than once, it becomes O(n^2).  Technically, traversing the list twice is O(2n), but sorting would be preferred in general (e.g., if he wanted to find the `m` largest numbers).